# Techniques to add flavour and aroma to beer with hops

Tags: taste, brewing, hops

I'm a hop lover, recently I found one of bests [`IIPA`](http://naparbier.com/menu/hop-doom/) I ever tasted ([I don't know if I can name beer / brand](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/can-i-link-a-beer-brand-or-specific-model-or-should-i-be-generic))

I've found at the bottom of the bottle, there are no yeast rests, but yes hop leafs. **`:)`** sweet!

One friend tell me this technike is called `bottle dry-hopping`, consisting in introducing a little bud of hop in each bottle.

I've heard about [`dry-hopping`](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/can-i-link-a-beer-brand-or-specific-model-or-should-i-be-generic) but before botteling the beer, also i know  `Hop Spider`, is a filter you fill with hop for the freezing step.

Three techniques are great and give nice results at the end, so:

- Anyone knows about other techniques using hops to add flavour and aroma **AFTER** cooking the beer?

Answer (score 3):

Some breweries use a hop "Torpedo", where the beer is forced through a chamber containing the desired aroma hops:

http://byo.com/hops/item/1899-torpedoes-away

You probably don't need one that big, though.

Answer (score 3):

I saw on Zythos Beer Festival in Leuven (Belgium) where they have a hop chamber (in glass) where the beer is going through when drafting into a glass.

[Similar like this](https://thenobleexperiment.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hopfilter3.jpg)

Comment: Often called a randle